# Using same channel for RPC call in RabbitMQ

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I have replaced CURL calls to API with RabbitMQ RPC messages. Everything works fine with [rabbitmq](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) example

Still it looks like implementation is wrong as every request opens connection, opens channel, sends message, waits for response, gets response, closes channel and closes connection.

How can i implement RabbitMQ RPC calls to use same connection for every request using PHP?

I using https://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib library

My implementation looks like this https://gist.github.com/fordnox/fa41e1233a207ec5416c

Using it like this:

```
$rpc = new RabbitRpc([/* config array */]);
$result = $rpc->callOnServer(1, ["foo":"bar"]);
```

Comment: What library or extension do you use? Show us some code from what you are trying to do.

Comment: Added gist with php class I am using. This class works in production and it works great. Still it looks like I am missing something to avoid opening and closing connections and channels.

Comment: Does that connection makes bottleneck for you? How does it take to connect to RabbitMQ & create channel and how long does it take to run the rest logic? For now, it looks like php-amqplib doesn't support persistent connections, but you have to investigate that. I can say for php-amqp extension that it has persistent connections support (though, channels are not persists between requests). But php-amqp extension has different than php-amqplib architecture.

Comment: Problem exists for request which takes longer than 15s to complete.  For example, request extracts tar.gz file on server.  Sometimes archive is big and this script closes connection after 15s. Error occurs when server tries to send response and exclusive queue is already gone. I thouhgt i could solve it by using same channel or same connection. I could also increase wait timeout,  but thats my last resort.